# Visual Studio 2022 - launch both api and react app

Tags: reactjs, .net-7.0

I'm learning React.js.
So, after create a API demo, i went to create an react app, using typescript.

`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

To centralize this - i add this to my api solution - as "Existing Web Site":

[image]

My doubt here is on how to launch both API and this react app by just press on "Start" button.
I assume is possible - as i saw it on an vue app, for example - but i'm lost here.
I set the solution to start both API and Web Site - but only "API" is launched.